# Fastest way to find compute function on DataFrame slices by column value (Python pandas)

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am trying to create a column on a data frame which contains the minimum of column A (the value column), for which column B (the id column) has a particular value. My code is really slow. I'm looking for a faster way to do this. Here is my little function:

```
def apply_by_id_value(df, id_col="id_col", val_col="val_col", offset_col="offset", f=min):
    for rid in set(df[id_col].values):
        df.loc[df[id_col] == rid, offset_col] =  f(df[df[id_col] == rid][val_col])
    return df
```

And example usage:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_col":[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   "val_col":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0]})

print df.head(10)
# output
   id_col  val_col
0       0      0.1
1       0      0.2
2       0      0.3
3       1      0.6
4       1      0.4
5       1      0.5
6       2      0.2
7       2      0.1
8       2      0.0

df = apply_by_id_value(df)
print df.head(10) 
# output

   id_col  val_col  offset
0       0      0.1     0.1
1       0      0.2     0.1
2       0      0.3     0.1
3       1      0.6     0.4
4       1      0.4     0.4
5       1      0.5     0.4
6       2      0.2     0.0
7       2      0.1     0.0
8       2      0.0     0.0
```

Some more context: In my real data, the "id_col" column has some 30000 or more unique values. This means that the data frame has to be sliced 30000 times. I imagine this is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'id_col' and then a [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) passing function 'min', this will return a Series aligned to your original df so you can add as a new column:

```
In [13]:

df = pd.DataFrame({"id_col":[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   "val_col":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0]})
df['offset'] = df.groupby('id_col').transform('min')
df
Out[13]:
   id_col  val_col  offset
0       0      0.1     0.1
1       0      0.2     0.1
2       0      0.3     0.1
3       1      0.6     0.4
4       1      0.4     0.4
5       1      0.5     0.4
6       2      0.2     0.0
7       2      0.1     0.0
8       2      0.0     0.0
```

**timings**

```
In [15]:

def apply_by_id_value(df, id_col="id_col", val_col="val_col", offset_col="offset", f=min):
    for rid in set(df[id_col].values):
        df.loc[df[id_col] == rid, offset_col] =  f(df[df[id_col] == rid][val_col])
    return df
%timeit apply_by_id_value(df)
%timeit df.groupby('id_col').transform('min')
100 loops, best of 3: 8.12 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.99 ms per loop
```

So the `groupby` and `transform` is faster on this dataset, I expect it to be significantly faster on your real dataset as it will scale better.

For a 800,000 row df I get the following timings:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 611 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 438 ms per loop
```

Comment: The groupby().transform() solution was "only" around 1,000 times faster in the real data ;-) Thanks so much! I knew it was there in the API, somewhere.

Comment: I guess it depends on the data distribution, on your dataset there were only 3 unique values so even concatenating this to itself 100,000 times the lookup times remained proportionally faster, but on your much more varied dataset the speed up is more significant, thanks for letting me know the speedup difference